# Would time dilation change both the position and direction of a spacecraft as seen from the earth?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time-dilation

Given that we can calculate all forces on a moving spacecraft including gravity, would the position and direction in which it is travelling be affected by time dilation ?

Comment: How do you mean this? If the ship goes from A to B, then it is seen going from A to B also from Earth. People on Earth and on the ship will disagree on how long that takes and how far it is, though.

Comment: Physical laws are invariant (exactly the same) for **all**  observers, no matter what their velocity. Time dilatation will not change that, we can always relate one set of measured values to another set from a relatively fast moving observer.

Answer (score 1):

> Given that we can calculate all forces on a moving spacecraft including gravity, would the position and direction in which it is travelling be affected by time dilation?

No, think about what the words **time dilation** mean.

To you in your fast moving spacecraft, everything inside the spaceship seems normal, time passes normally, the measurements of the size of your instruments, for example,  agree with the figures you calculated on Earth.

You, looking around inside the ship, will not notice anything different, (looking outside the ship is a different matter, but this will just confuse the issue).

But to an outside observer, who can see both you and the instruments of the ship, things look distorted. He would view your dashboard clock as taking far longer to go from a time of 10.50.05  to a time of 10.50.06 than you do. To you, it takes a second, but depending on your speed relative to him,  it could, for example, take 5 seconds on **his** clock.

That what time dilation means, there is no absolute  time of 1 second duration that you can agree on, but there are laws, the Lorentz transformations, that allow both of you to reconcile your measurements.

My point is that physical laws are the same everywhere, including the direction your spaceship moves when the main engine is on, or when thrusters move it sideways, but your **perception and measurements** of these movements will vary depending on how fast you travel.

Comment: O.k. Let me try to explain what I mean more specifically. Say a spacecraft is accelerated away from the earth and then maintains a cruising speed of 10,000 miles per hour. On the earth the position of the spacecraft is predicted after one year of travel. Now this will be calculated at 10,000 miles per hour, the hour being an earth hour. Now the spacecraft has experienced time dilation and there measurement of time will be different from ours on earth. So the distance travelled will not agree with calculations made on the earth, as there hour will be marginally different from our hour.

Comment: The distance travelled by the spacecraft is controlled **only** by how much power it's rocket engine gives it. It is in no way determined by who measures it.  Say the spacecraft turns around when its fuel guage is exactly half empty.  If we accept your pov, then the spacecraft will/will not get back to Earth, ( for a given amount of fuel) depending on who measures it, which can't be right.

Comment: I disagree. As soon as the rocket reaches 10,000 miles an hour the rocket engine is stopped and the rocket then continues at this speed. As we know distance travelled will be

Comment: Cont'd - the speed of the rocket and the time that has elapsed. Now the time on the rocket is different from the time on the earth. So the distance covered will also be different. Therefore the predicted  position of the spacecraft will be also be different after say 10 years. If time dilation is a real event.

Comment: I was wrong to use the fuel gauge :) It's a spaceship not a car, but I was trying to think of an independent measure, as we would both agree the mass of fuel is invariant, I think. Time dilatation is real in the sense that the observers differ in their measure of time. Each thinks the other clock is running slow.  I am pushed for time (sorry: ) myself at the moment, but I will edit my answer asap. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer heavily depends on the direction of relative motion between the two frames.

So, suppose that $v_x$,$v_y$ and $v_z$ are the 3 components of the velocities of the spacecraft with respect to a global stationary observer.

Now, if the observer is moving with a velocity $V_X$,$V_Y$, then $v_x$ and $v_y$ with respect to the observer will be affected by the STR velocity addition rule. Although there is no relative motion with respect to the z- component, $v_z$ will still be affected by time dilation.

Thus now you end up with $v^{'}$ which has different components that $v$ and hence has a different direction with respect to the observer.

However, technically, it is not correct to attribute this to "time-dilation" alone and may be thought of as STR effects as a whole.